# Куда вставлять 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' в node js?

Tags: node.js, express

Делая запрос с

```
http://localhost:3000
```

на

```
http://localhost:4200
```

выдаются ошибка с CORS политикой.

Нагуглил, что надо в ответ `response` вставлять:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
```

Но куда именно?

Comment: В HTTP-заголовки ответа того сервера, которому направляется запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) - это Express middleware, которое может быть использовано для включения CORS с различными опциями.

```bsh
$ npm install cors
```

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let corsOptions = {
    origin : ['http://localhost:3000'],
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```